# verbatim vertical bar in org table

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I am trying to have a vertical bar inside a verbatim environment as part of an org-mode table. Following https://orgmode.org/manual/Built_002din-table-editor.html#FOOT20 I have tried this:

```
| =find -name "*Lafontaine*" \vert xargs okular &= | finds files |
```

where `\vert` is meant to be the pipe character. Yet, not surprisingly, `\vert` is output verbatim, and not as "|" as intended.

How can I get this work please?

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try leaving the \vert out of the verbatim environment:

```
| =find -name "*Lafontaine*"= \vert =xargs okular &=   | finds files |
```

by ending the first verbatim before the \vert and starting a second verbatim after it.